# websphere application server - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property reuse-instanceis not supported

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am receiving the following exception when trying to access an XSD schema file from the WebSphere server.

WebSphere version is 8.5.5.0.

```
[6/22/16 13:02:31:158 IST]     FFDC Exception:javax.servlet.ServletException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doGet ProbeId:231 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet@93f57806
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property reuse-instance is not supported
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.processXsdRequest(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1278)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doGet(WASAxis2Servlet.java:522)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    ...
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    ...
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property reuse-instanceis not supported
    at com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrWriterFactory.setProperty(ZephyrWriterFactory.java:113)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPDialect.makeThreadSafe(SJSXPDialect.java:75)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils$8.run(StAXUtils.java:647)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:229)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.newXMLOutputFactory(StAXUtils.java:623)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLOutputFactory_perClassLoader(StAXUtils.java:687)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLOutputFactory(StAXUtils.java:326)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLOutputFactory(StAXUtils.java:291)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamWriter(StAXUtils.java:358)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamWriter(StAXUtils.java:353)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:139)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.processXsdRequest(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1257)
    ... 34 more

Reporter BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet@93f57806
javax.servlet.GenericServlet::config:null
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_DELETE:DELETE
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_HEAD:HEAD
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_GET:GET
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_OPTIONS:OPTIONS
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_POST:POST
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_PUT:PUT
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::METHOD_TRACE:TRACE
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::HEADER_IFMODSINCE:If-Modified-Since
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::HEADER_LASTMOD:Last-Modified
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::LSTRING_FILE:javax.servlet.http.LocalStrings
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet::lStrings BEGIN:java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@45b429bb
 java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@45b429bb
 END:java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@45b429bb

org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::serialVersionUID:3105135058353738906
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::log BEGIN:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@75c290dd
 org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::c:class org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet
 org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger::_log:null
 END:org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger@75c290dd

org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT:CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::SESSION_ID:SessionId
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet::metadataQueryParamNames BEGIN:java.util.HashSet@1c88ff33
 {
 policy
 wsdl
 xsd
 wsdl2
 }
 END:java.util.HashSet@1c88ff33
```

Anyone can provide some enlightenment on this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For "Property reuse-instance" related errors which have same stack trace logs, they are about apache axiom.
Websphere Application Server full profile uses  and exposes org.apache.* open source libraries to applications running on the server. 
You might encounter problems when your application uses the same libraries at difference versions that are deployed within your application.
To fix this issue, you can change the class loader from parent first to parent last. [Reference](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=UxA3CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=ibm%20java%207%20axiom&source=bl&ots=JlF1jqRPB1&sig=z9_t75eh4GnYS5RAUN9SBa36A0s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAnMvt0sfNAhUBwxQKHfyfD3kQ6AEIWTAJ#v=onepage&q=ibm%20java%207%20axiom&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace indicates that the JAX-WS runtime in WebSphere is attempting to use SJSXP instead of WebSphere's own StAX implementation (XLXP 2). Things may have changed in newer WebSphere versions, but [it used to be the case](http://veithen.github.io/2013/10/02/broken-by-design-websphere-stax.html) that this only occurs if the following two conditions are met:

- The class loading policy for the application is set to parent last.
- The application contains SJSXP.

One option is therefore to change your application so that at least one of these conditions is no longer met. If that's not possible because the code in your application somehow relies on them, then your best bet is to try switching to another SJSXP version.